# Problemas con mi consulta sql en Oracle con función add_months

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

espero y me puedan ayudar, tengo un problema con mi consulta sql, lo que pasa es que quiero traer los registros mediante una fecha que tengo en un campo, esos registros quiero que sean de un mes atras, por ejm si columna tiene esta esta 18/08/20, que en mi consulta si llega a existir 18/07/20 me la traiga y si no pues que no la regrese, hice esta sentencia pero el resultado no es lo que espero miren:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese resultado que está seleccionado no es el correcto ya que aun no estamos en septiembre,esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT cta_que_factura, tipo_documento,id_estatus, uuid, FECHA_CREACION
from complemento_pago
        where tipo_documento =4 and id_estatus =6 AND UUID IS NULL
            and FECHA_CREACION >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)
        and FECHA_CREACION >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1);;
```

Gracias a la respuesta de Luis Cazares ya pude arreglar la consulta, solo que apenas me hicieron un cambio, el problema es el siguiente:

Lo que se requiere ahora que ya no sea estatico en el metodo de addmonths sino que por medio de otra tabla que tiene un campo llamado valor me recorra los dias, la tabla sería la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El registro que está marcado tiene que traer el dia 5 de julio del 2020, es decir irme hacía atrás la fecha del 5 de julio la conté a partir de hoy 20 de julio del 2020, la pregunta es:

¿Como podría cambiar esta función

```
FECHA_CREACION >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)
```

Por la columna de la tabla **parámetros** que está marcado en azul, es decir, el numero 45 y otra cosa también, la tabla parametros no tiene relación de claves primarias o cualquier otro campo con el de la tabla de **complemento_pago** del que tengo la consulta, espero y me dé a entender por favor, quedo al pendiente de sus recomendaciones y si en algo no se entiende con gusto les responderé.

Comment: Podría intentar con la función [NUMTODSINTERVAL()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm) y una subconsulta.

Comment: Hola, pero como haría esa subconsulta, con que campo lo puedo relacionar ambas tablas, complemento_pago y parametros, ya que no hay ninguno relación tal, soy nuevo en esto de las subconsultas, habría manera de que me puedas proporcionar un ejm por favor? Saludos

Comment: [Ejemplo de subconsultas](https://jorgesanchez.net/manuales/sql/select-subconsultas-sql2016.html).

Answer (score 0):

Te falta agregar el límite superior del mes.

```
SELECT cta_que_factura, tipo_documento,id_estatus, uuid, FECHA_CREACION
from complemento_pago
        where tipo_documento =4 and id_estatus =6 AND UUID IS NULL
            and FECHA_CREACION >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)
            and FECHA_CREACION <  trunc(sysdate,'mm');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me ayudó, pero apenas me la cambiaron en mi trabajo, voy actualizar mi pregunta y expondré el problema XD

Answer (score 0):

Si lees de una tabla la cantidad de dias, ese dato debe ser un entero y podrias hacer algo asi:

```
FECHA_CREACION >= (select trunc(sysdate) - (select valor from parámetros where id_parametro = 334) from dual)
```